# Javascript to detect if a div is contained inside another and when is not anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a question.

I need to detect using javacript (or JQuery) when a div is contained inside another and when is not contained anymore.

I need something like this:

```
if(div #result).contains (div #dbResults) then{#explainMsg.hide, #errorMsg.hide;
if(div #result).not contains (div #dbResults) anymore then {#errorMsg.show}.
```

the "not contains anymore" part is because the div's are added dynamically server side.

Obliviously is not the code, but what i need to obtain.

thanks

Comment: [http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/)

Comment: Have you tried the jQuery API docs? `find` or `children` seem to be what you are looking for: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 1):

```
var show = !!$('div#result').find('#dbResults').length; 
// true if #dbResults is found

// toggle visibility based on match:
$('#errorMsg').toggle(show);
```

Comment: this works in part.
I can obtain the true and false, but when the divs are not anymore inside the parent, the errorMsg doesn't appear.

Comment: @user3668732 You need to run this everytime the state changes.

Comment: the problem is that i have a live searchbox and on every key up the divs contained inside the #result changes until i have no more divs if, for example, i write something not listed on the db. I added it inside "on key up" function

Comment: @user3668732 You could combine it when you get the db search result e.g. `var show = !!(dbresult.length && $('div#result').find('#dbResults').length);`

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
$( "div#result:has('div#dbResults')" )
```

**[:has(selector)](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)**

OR

```
$( "div#result" ).has( "div#dbResults" )
```

**[.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)** - matches the descendants.

```
if($( "div#result" ).has( "div#dbResults" ).length){
    $('#errorMsg').hide();
}
else{
    $('#errorMsg').show();
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **native** method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains

```
node.contains( otherNode )
```

Proceeding your comments, it is looks like you want to use some DOMTreeChange event, to catch the moment when the div is disappear. But the correct way is to "connect" somehow to the functional which is do an actual tree change (removes your div etc.) and do what you need when it is happens.